# Why is it possible to assign a number to a pointer variable in C?

Tags: c, pointers, variables

Why is there no error if we simply assign an integer to a pointer variable? What happens in this code:

```
void main()
{
   int i=19;
   int *ptr;
   ptr=i;
   printf("Value of ptr is %d",ptr);
}

// output :Value of ptr is 19
```

Comment: A pointer is, more formally, a "pointer variable", so yes, it is a variable and you can use it as a variable.

Comment: But you will get some warning doing so

Answer (score 4):

> Why is there no error if we simply assign an integer to a pointer
>   variable?

Because the `-pedantic` (or `-pedantic-errors`) flag is implicitely turned off.

From `man gcc`:

> Issue all the warnings demanded by strict ISO C and ISO C++; reject
>   all programs that use forbidden extensions, and some other programs
>   that do not follow ISO C and ISO C++.  For ISO C, follows the version
>   of the ISO C standard specified by any `-std` option used.

By the C Standard, it's not allowed to assign integer to object of pointer type without **explicit cast** (with the exception of null pointer constant). The relevant clause is (emphasis mine):

> #### C11 §6.5.16.1/1 Simple assignment
>
> One of the following **shall** hold:
>
> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type,
>     and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue
>     conversion) both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified
>     versions of compatible types, and the type pointed to by the left has
>     all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;

The next two bullets are about `void` pointers and `NULL`. Neither of three applies here, hence the *constraint violation* occurs.

Answer (score 1):

In C, an *object pointer* like `int *` can convert to a `void *`.  A `void *` pointer can be converted to/from an integer.  But not all integer values may convert to a pointer.

Optional types `intptr_t/uintptr_t` allow round tripping `int * --> void* --> intptr_t/uintptr_t --> void* --> int*`

OP's code may fail as direct conversion is not well specified.

```
int i=19;
int *ptr;
ptr=i;   // problem - 19 may cause UB
printf("Value of ptr is %d",ptr); // problem, wrong printf specifier.
```

Better Example

```
#include <stdint.h>

int i = 867-5309;  // some integer
printf("Value of i is %d\n", i);

int *i_ptr = &i;
printf("Value of i_ptr is %p\n", (void*) i_ptr);

intptr_t i_ptr_i = (intptr_t)(void*) i_ptr;
// C lacks a specifier for intptr_t/uintptr_t, so use a wide type
printf("Value of i_ptr_i is %jd\n", (intmax_t) i_ptr_i);

int *i_ptr2 = (void*) i_ptr_i;
printf("Value of i_ptr2 is %p\n", (void*) i_ptr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is, more formally, a "pointer variable". That means there is a memory location where the value is stored, just like any other variable.

And just like any other variable, there are operations defined for the type of variable. To a pointer variable you can assign an (unsigned) integer value that should represent a memory adress. Taking the address of another variable and assigning it to the pointer variable is an example.

Dereferencing a pointer variable means to look at what the pointer is pointing to. If the pointer is not pointing to a valid address, the hardware and the operating system may abort your program ("seg fault").

Answer (score 0):

The other answers already explained very well that it is allowed and what happens when you do it.

But I think it is also important to mention why it is allowed. You are allowed to set a specific address to a pointer because when implementing embedded software, using microcontrollers, many times you need to write to very specific addresses. Like the addresses of the registers which control the peripherals, like ports, clock operation, A/D converter, etc.